# Can I use web3js without setting the provider?

Tags: web3js, web3-providers

So I have two NodeJS applications, both implementing web3js.
The first node is used for creating and signing transactions, then it sends raw signed transaction to the second node. Finally, the second node submit it to Ethereum network using the set provider.

However, I wonder can I use web3js on the first node "without" connecting it to any provider? We do not want the first node to connect to Internet at all (except connecting to second node) since it contains private keys of accounts.

Comment: How does the first node send the transactions to the second node?

Comment: I think you'll find it in your best interest to avoid keeping private information on your node. If I understand correctly, then you want this node to maintain an account which will be unlocked forever, instead of sending the private key to the node every time you need to unlock it. If that is the case, then please be advised that both options are potentially unsecured. The first one is unsecured if somebody gains access to your node. The second one is unsecured if somebody gains access to your connection.

Comment: AFAIK, the best way to deal with things here is to sign the transaction with your private key BEFORE you send it to the node. Then, the node has no knowledge of secret information - it doesn't store such information and it doesn't receive such information.

Comment: @cogitoergosum we use local networkto communicate between two nodes

Comment: So anyone hacking the second node will eventually be able to hack the first node.

Comment: @goodvibration thx for raising this concern. However, I just want to solve the first issue that is it possible to use Web3js without setting the provider or not. Then I can move on to the security issue that you just mentioned. In addition, whether web3js can be used with or without the provider also affect the internal design of my service.

Comment: What I'm trying to tell you, is that your can solve your original problem in a different manner, such that will not yield another problem to solve later. If I understand your intentions correctly and you want to maintain an unlocked account on node #1, then I think that there's a better way.

Comment: Or use a unidirectional serial communication between the two computers. Write your raw signed tx to a serial out and read it from the second computer. No one would be able to revert the communication on the serial link to gain access to the 1st one.

Comment: Have you tried to pass a null provider?

Comment: @NicolasMassart I tried and it threw an error. So one solution I came up is running a local Ethereum test network so my application does not have to connect to the internet.

Comment: @richard yes that's what I thought. Web3 constructor requires a provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need an instance of web3 to sign a transaction. For example you can use `ethereumjs-tx` to create the transaction and `ethereumjs-wallet` to manage your private key.

We have two servers: A connected to ethereum network where the transaction is created, ie filling correct nonce and updated gas price; and B that exposes an api to sign transactions.

Comment: Yes, it seems web3 instance requires a provider as its parameter. So we have to turn to ethereumjs-tx to sign the transaction.

We have tried running the local ethereum network [ganache-cli](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli) as its provider to make web3js works (so we do not have to change our current code). It works fine.